# Алгоритм Беллмана-Форда для цикла с отрицательным весом

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных, циклы, псевдокод

Может кто-нибудь доступно объяснить пример работы(для случая в заголовке) данного алгоритма(желательно в псевдокоде,либо своими словами)?

Comment: e-maxx.ru смотрели?

Comment: Да смотрел,но примеры реализации не совсем удачные для меня.. глянуть бы,как данный алгоритм на языке js реализуется в том числе с поиском цикла с отрицательным весом

Comment: Так вы же просите псевдокод? А шлвлоиье теперь про js

Comment: Это псевдокод? Видимо я ничего о псевдокоде не знаю.. ладно спасибо за совет,буду разбмраться.. что то уже на хабре нарыл.. может удасться переварить этот алгоритм

Comment: Ну, а чем он не нравится? Собственно, что-то написано на c++-подобном коде. Если по нему есть вопросы, то можете задать. Я отвечу.